# Big query SQL - Count elements from a string

Tags: sql, string, select, count, google-bigquery

I have an example string data as below.

```
+----------------------------+
|          Items             |
|----------------------------|
| A >> B >> C                |
| A >> A >> B                |
| B >> B >> C >> C >> A      |
| B >> B >> B >> C >> A >> D |
+----------------------------+
```

Take the "Items" in the first row as an example, this "Items" contains three elements, namely A, B and C.
I want to calculate the number of each element in order.
Besides, I will only focus on 3 elements so I will ignore element 'D' in the last "Items".

Here's what I want:

```
+----------------------------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
|          Items             |  Item1  | I1_Count |  Item2  | I2_Count |  Item3  | I3_Count |
|----------------------------|---------|----------|---------|----------|---------|----------|
| A >> B >> C                |    A    |     1    |    B    |     1    |    C    |     1    | 
| A >> A >> B                |    A    |     2    |    B    |     1    |   NULL  |    NULL  |
| A >> B >> B >> C >> C      |    A    |     1    |    B    |     1    |    C    |     2    |
| B >> B >> C >> C >> A      |    B    |     2    |    C    |     2    |    A    |     1    |
| B >> B >> B >> C >> A >> D |    B    |     3    |    C    |     1    |    A    |     1    |
+----------------------------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
```

How can I implement it in SQL(I use Google Bigquery)?

Thanks a million!

Comment: My advice: Change this table design and get each path value onto a separate record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unnest the string and then apply some aggregation logic:

```
with t as (
      select 'A >> B >> C' as items union all
      select 'A >> A >> B' as items union all
      select 'B >> B >> C >> C >> A' as items union all
      select 'B >> B >> B >> C >> A >> D' as items 
     )
select t.*,
       (select as struct max(case when n = 1 then item end) as item_1,
               max(case when n = 1 then cnt end) as item_1_cnt,
               max(case when n = 2 then item end) as item_2,
               max(case when n = 2 then cnt end) as item_2_cnt,
               max(case when n = 3 then item end) as item_3,
               max(case when n = 3 then cnt end) as item_3_cnt
        from (select item, dense_rank() over (order by min(n)) as n, count(*) as cnt
              from unnest(split(t.items, ' >> ')) item with offset n
              group by item
             ) x
       ).*
from t;
```

The innermost subquery transforms the string into rows, with a counter.  This is then aggregated to order the items by the first time they appear -- along with the count of the item.

Finally, these are aggregated into the different columns that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! It helps me a lot!

Comment: @LucasLee . . . You should accept one of the answers.  I would point out that this was first by hours.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select items,
  arr[offset(0)].item as Item1,
  arr[offset(0)].cnt as I1_Count,
  arr[safe_offset(1)].item as Item2,
  arr[safe_offset(1)].cnt as I2_Count,
  arr[safe_offset(2)].item as Item3,
  arr[safe_offset(2)].cnt as I3_Count
from (
  select items, 
    array(
      select as struct item, count(*) as cnt
      from unnest(split(Items, ' >> ')) item with offset
      group by item
      order by min(offset)
    ) arr
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
```

if to apply above to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. This helps me a lot!

Comment: Hello master, I got a extended question and I've added in my question part. Please see the paragraph "The extended question was created on 2020/11/9...". Hope you can give me another light. Thank you!

Comment: your original question is fully answered! you should revert your post to original question and post your new question as a NEW question/post

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thank you for the reply. I've reverted my post to original question and posted another new question here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64762440/) . Sorry for my ignorance on the manners.

Comment: sure. no problem. see the answer there