# Big query SQL - Count elements from a string but in order

Tags: sql, string, select, count, google-bigquery

I have an example string data as below.

```
+----------------------------+
|          Items             |
|----------------------------|
| A >> B >> C                |
| A >> A >> B                |
| B >> C >> B >> B >> A      |
| B >> B >> C >> C >> A      |
| B >> A >> B >> C >> A >> D |
+----------------------------+
```

Take the "Items" in the first row as an example, this "Items" contains three elements, namely A, B and C.
I want to calculate the number of each element in order.
Besides, I only focus on 3 elements so I ignore 'C >> A >> D' in the final "Items".

Here's what I want:

```
+----------------------------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
|          Items             |  Item1  | I1_Count |  Item2  | I2_Count |  Item3  | I3_Count |
|----------------------------|---------|----------|---------|----------|---------|----------|
| A >> B >> C                |    A    |     1    |    B    |     1    |    C    |     1    | 
| A >> A >> B                |    A    |     2    |    B    |     1    |   NULL  |    NULL  |
| B >> C >> B >> B >> A      |    B    |     1    |    C    |     1    |    B    |     2    |
| B >> B >> C >> C >> A      |    B    |     2    |    C    |     2    |    A    |     1    |
| B >> A >> B >> C >> A >> D |    B    |     1    |    A    |     1    |    B    |     1    |
+----------------------------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
```

How can I implement it in SQL(I use Google Bigquery)?

Thanks a million!

Comment: . . How is this different from your other question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64658510/big-query-sql-count-elements-from-a-string#64658510

Comment: The third item is 'B >> C >> B >> B >> A'. but I need the answer B: 1 count, C: 1 count , B: 2 count. Using the answers from previous can't get this answer so that's why I post another new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (and is just simple adjustment of the solution for your previous question)

```
#standardSQL
select items,
  arr[offset(0)].item as Item1,
  arr[offset(0)].cnt as I1_Count,
  arr[safe_offset(1)].item as Item2,
  arr[safe_offset(1)].cnt as I2_Count,
  arr[safe_offset(2)].item as Item3,
  arr[safe_offset(2)].cnt as I3_Count
from (
  select items, 
    array(select as struct item, count(1) cnt
    from unnest(
    array(select as struct item, countif(not flag) over(order by offset) grp
    from unnest(array(
        select as struct item, offset, item = lag(item) over(order by offset) flag
        from unnest(split(Items, ' >> ')) item with offset
      )))
    ) 
    group by item, grp
    order by grp
    ) arr  
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Cool, this is a great solution because it's very clear and short. Thanks Mikhail!

Answer (score 1):

Below is for the less likely case when your A, B, C, D are actually finite set of letters or words that you know in advance (BigQuery Standard SQL):

```
#standardSQL
select items,   
  left(arr[offset(0)], 1) as Item1,
  length(arr[offset(0)]) as I1_Count,
  left(arr[safe_offset(1)], 1) as Item2,
  length(arr[safe_offset(1)]) as I2_Count,
  left(arr[safe_offset(2)], 1) as Item3,
  length(arr[safe_offset(2)]) as I3_Count
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest([struct(regexp_extract_all(replace(Items, ' >> ', ''), r'(A+|B+|C+|D+)') as arr)])
```

if applied to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Moreover, just adding more lines will cover more sequences

```
#standardSQL
select items,   
  left(arr[offset(0)], 1) as Item1,
  length(arr[offset(0)]) as I1_Count,
  left(arr[safe_offset(1)], 1) as Item2,
  length(arr[safe_offset(1)]) as I2_Count,
  left(arr[safe_offset(2)], 1) as Item3,
  length(arr[safe_offset(2)]) as I3_Count,
  left(arr[safe_offset(3)], 1) as Item4,
  length(arr[safe_offset(3)]) as I4_Count,
  left(arr[safe_offset(4)], 1) as Item5,
  length(arr[safe_offset(4)]) as I5_Count,
  left(arr[safe_offset(5)], 1) as Item6,
  length(arr[safe_offset(5)]) as I6_Count
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest([struct(regexp_extract_all(replace(Items, ' >> ', ''), r'(A+|B+|C+|D+)') as arr)])
```

with output

[image]

Comment: The plus SQL is aslo benefit to me. Awesome!